# Missing type specifier on virtual function implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-c++, virtual-functions

I have the following structure of classes (in C++):

```
template<T>
class A {
    class B {
        class C_Base {
            virtual int foo(const T &a, const T &b) = 0;
        };

        template<U>
        class C final : public C_Base {
            const U &x;
            virtual int foo(const T &a, const T &b) {
                return x(a, b);
            }
        };
    };
};
```

However, MSVC gives me the error `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.` on the definition of `foo` inside `C`. Why is this, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You are making something up. Trying to compile this code will immediately fail at the very first line: `template<T>`. Fixing these errors makes it compile in MSVC without any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `typename` keyword.

```
template<typename T>
//-------^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: What a long day it has been... thank you, I can't believe I forgot something like this...